# Resources.getSystem().getString vs just placing a string

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out why this works fine:

```
JSONObject currentFilm = filmArray.getJSONObject(i);

// Extract the value for individual keys from JSONObject results
int voteCount = currentFilm.getInt("vote_count");
```

but this throws an exception for runtime error in AsyncTask:

```
JSONObject currentFilm = filmArray.getJSONObject(i);

// Extract the value for individual keys from JSONObject results
int voteCount = currentFilm.getInt(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.vote_count));
```

Is it not fetching the vote_count string "vote_count" from the String xml file? Shouldn't it be the same thing?

Stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resources.getSystem()` references to the system resources and not your app specific resource. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getSystem()):

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to **only
>   system resources** (**no application resources**), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
>   on orientation, etc).

So `Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.vote_count)` would search in system only and not in your app. It won't find it since there is no String with id `vote_count` in the system.

use `context.getResources().getString(R.string.vote_count)` or `context.getString(R.string.vote_count)` instead.

Comment: ya that makes sense. I only used the Resources.getSystem() because context.getResources() didn't work but I didn't really understand the difference. I'm trying to get the context of a utility java class and I'm confused on how to do it properly...

Comment: You need to pass context from Activity/Service/BroadcastReceiver to your Utility method.

Comment: Is there a way to get the context in a static method? I can read in the context to the Utility class using the BroadcastReceiver or extending the main activity but I can't read it into static method if that makes any sense. I'm not sure if I'm using the terminology correctly.

Comment: You can just create : `static methodName (Context context)`. When you call it from Activity, you can call `ClassName.methodName (this)` like wise from BroadcastReceiver pass the context.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar for your help. I think I got it to work. However, after all that I reverted back to what I initially had because I shouldn't be using strings from an XML file when I'm using them as a key for an API query. It completely makes sense why but I had a code reviewer tell me I should which is why I was trying to make the change. But then another code reviewer told me to not do that. All over the place...

Comment: They are absolutely right. The purpose of strings.xml is for facilitating the localization at ease and since your API KEY doesn't need this and should be more private you shouldn't put it in strings.xml. if you feel just for your questions scope the answer I gave was useful, then remember to mark it as accepted so that others can benefit too.